# How to start Redux in React Native

Tags: react-native, redux

I am new to React Native and I want to add Redux to my project.

And I want to know if redux store values are saved when app is exited.

If it is not saved, how can I handle this problem?

In web development, we use cookie and local storage. Thanks in advance.

[Edit]
If I must use async storage, is there any easy way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

There is **Ayncstorage** for react native which is equivalent to localstorage in browser.

You can refer this
https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage

Or you can use **redux-persist** if you want to persist redux store when app exits which would otherwise get lost.

https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist

Answer (score 0):

Redux state is usually emptied upon when an app is exited (not minimised).

What you should to instead is to use [AsyncStorage](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage) to persist your access token, and get them from same storage when the app starts. You can do this in a `didMount` lifecycle, or any other means you may choose.